# using recursion to get sub strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, recursion, substring

how can I use recursion to find the amount of 'a' that is in a string:

example:
get_a('halloa') -> 2

here is what I have:

```
    def get_a(string):
        '''
        return how many times a exist in the string using recursion
        '''
        if string == '':
            return 0
        if string[0] == 'a':
            return 1
    return get_a(string[1:])
```

Comment: Do you _really_ have to use recursion for this?

Comment: @PM2Ring: Maybe it's an exercise in functional-style programming.

Comment: @FredLarson Sure, or at least an exercise in learning about recursion. Otherwise the OP could simply use the `.count` method.

Answer (score 6):

the problem in your code is that you stop the recursion when you find the first `a`. You'll want to call `get_a` and collect the `a`s you've already found:

```
def get_a(string):
    '''
    return how many times a exist in the string using recursion
    '''
    if string == '':
        return 0
    if string[0] == 'a':
        return 1 + get_a(string[1:])
    return get_a(string[1:])
```